# I get no data using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqxgrid

I use the code below to get data from a database. No issues here.....

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM takenlijst";
$from = 0; 
$to = 999;
$query .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$to;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$taken[] = array(
'taaknummer' => $row['taaknummer'],
'naam' => $row['naam'],
'taak' => $row['taak'],
'prioriteit' => $row['prioriteit'],
'datum' => $row['datum']
  );
}
echo json_encode($taken);
```

However, when i use the code below i get no data. What am i doing wrong?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/scripts/demos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // prepare the data
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
            { name: 'taaknummer', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'naam', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'taak', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'prioriteit', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'datum', type: 'string'}
            ],
            url: 'http://www.site.com/management/takenlijstdata.php',
            cache: false
        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            source: dataAdapter,
            columns: [
            { text: 'Taaknummer', datafield: 'taaknummer', width: 250},
            { text: 'Naam', datafield: 'naam', width: 150 },
            { text: 'Taak', datafield: 'taak', width: 180 },
            { text: 'Prioriteit', datafield: 'prioriteit', width: 200 },
            { text: 'Datum', datafield: 'datum', width: 120 }
            ]
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
 <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The echo displays the data correctly. Even when i output the data to a txt file it can be read but not when i try to read it from this code.

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements. Mysql is outdated

Comment: Tried hitting your data url in a browser and looked for warnings/errors? If ANYTHING other than the json data you'd like to have get output you'll get json parse errors on the receiving end. Did you check your browser's javascript console for errors? Check your server's access log to see if your JS code ever even hits up the server?

Comment: These are the error messages i get... "SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead" , "Error: http://www.gamepedia.nl/jquery/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one" , "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."